# ¿Que usar para conseguir que un submenú solo se visualice cuando el usuario pase el mouse por el menú?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, wordpress, menú

Este es el código de mi menú:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background:#585656;">

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                    <?php 
                            wp_nav_menu(
                                array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'superior',
                                    'container'      =>'div',                           
                                    'container_class'=>'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                    'container_id'   =>'navbarNavDropdown',
                                    'items_wrap'     => '<ul  class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
                                    'menu_class'     => 'nav-item',

                                )
                            );    
                    ?>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues me da como resultado el menú de la imagen, sin embargo no se como hacer para decirle al código que por ejemplo Blog y contacto son el submenu  de Acerca de, es mejor dicho que esto no se visualicen de esa forma, sino que se visualicen cuando el usuario pase el mouse por el menú, solo me queda decir que estoy realizando este tema con bootstrap para wordpress

Comment: Por lo que comentas el submenú está bien creado, la pregunta debería ser algo como **¿Que usar para conseguir que un submenú solo se visualice cuando el usuario pase el mouse por el menú?** La respuesta podría ser usando `css`y/o `javascript`, creo que deberías añadir estas etiquetas y de paso añadir que has intentado por ahora. Repasa los apartados [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Claro,muchas gracias

Comment: En tu código no veo que hagas mención a los menús o submenús.

Comment: el codigo  esta dentro de la funcion wp_nav－menu que es una funcion de wordpress para crear menus dinamicos, utilizo los estilos de bootstrap como podra ver en los class

Comment: Como se llama la clase de los submenus?

Comment: Cuando se genera wordpress le agrega la clase submenu